# Best Way to Determine if Address is in NY Tri State Area

Tags: geo

I'm working on a coding problem where I potentially need to flag any locations in user entered addresses that are in the NY Tri-State area.

Unfortunately I'm not that familiar with the US addressing system, so I'm not sure of the best way to start.

Other than using a geoshape and checking if the lat/longs of the locations fall within the shape, is there a simpler/more efficient way of checking if a US address is in that area?

Comment: Use a zip code system. Zip codes are what define an area.

Comment: Is there a list somewhere of which codes are in the Tri-State area? I found a list for NYC, but the numbers don't appear to be contiguous, e.g there are gaps in the numbers.

Comment: There are usually gaps in the numbers so you should be okay with the ones you found